# Finding the symmetric difference between two arrays

Tags: javascript, array-difference

I need to find any differences between two arrays in the elements and push said elements onto a new array that is then returned in the end. I have pulled a function from this website through searching that has the intended purpose of counting the number of times an element occurs in an array and returning that. First I have concatenated the two arrays together, then applied this function (modified it to fit my problem as well as I could). I then tried to push the elements that were different (didn't occur twice) to the new array. My code of course doesn't work and I am also new to Javascript, so please be easy on me.

Below is some code of what I have tried, which doesn't pass any tests:

```
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  var newArr = [];

  let tempArr = arr1.concat(arr2);

  function countInArray(array, what) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === what) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (countInArray(tempArr, tempArr[i]) < 2) {
      newArr.push(tempArr[i]);
    } 
}


  return newArr;
}
```

If you provide any code please try to break it down for me so that I can understand better and learn.

Comment: do you have some data and the wanted result? what about more than one of the same item?

Comment: "["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "pink wool", "dead shrub"], ["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"] should return ["pink wool"]."

Comment: I'll add some more of the intended results below.

Comment: [1, "calf", 3, "piglet"], [7, "filly"] should return [1, "calf", 3, "piglet", 7, "filly"].

Comment: [], ["snuffleupagus", "cookie monster", "elmo"] should return an array with three items.

Comment: [1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] should return an array with one item.

Comment: I don't think it says anything about things occuring more than once, but if something were to occur twice, I would assume that it would have to occur twice in the other array.

Comment: Before we get to other, easier, more elegant solutions, could we first see if my line of logic can work out? I'd like some sense of resolution/closure with the way I started the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option by making few changes to your code

1. Return **count** for countInArray (currently it returns undefined)

`function countInArray(array, what) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === what) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count
}`

2. Remove calling countInArray inside countInArray method
3. Run For Loop for tempArr to compare with other each value of tempArr

`for (var j = 0; j < tempArr.length; j++) {
       if (countInArray(tempArr, tempArr[j]) < 2) {
         newArr.push(tempArr[j]);
       } 
    }`

Working code :

```js
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  let tempArr = arr1.concat(arr2);
  let newArr = [];
  function countInArray(array, what) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === what) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count
}
  
    for (var j = 0; j < tempArr.length; j++) {
       if (countInArray(tempArr, tempArr[j]) < 2) {
         newArr.push(tempArr[j]);
       } 
    }


  return newArr;
}


let arr1 = ["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "pink wool", "dead shrub"]
let arr2 = ["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"]
console.log(diffArray(arr1, arr2))

let arr3 = [1, "calf", 3, "piglet"]
let arr4 =  [7, "filly"]
console.log(diffArray(arr3, arr4))
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/OYNdZX?editors=1010

Comment: beautiful. Thank you so much for showing me how I could take what I started with and modify it a bit to make it work! I really appreciate it. I find that adding resolution to the solution I initially tried helps me learn a lot more. After I get some closure to my initial line of logic, I then feel comfortable exploring other solutions.

Comment: I'm sure there's some type of input into this problem with two arrays that wouldn't work for this code, I can tell that just saying `(countInArray(tempArr, tempArr[j]) < 2)` might yield some issues, but, for the arrays they provided, it works, and I'm happy with that for now.

Comment: yes, with those inputs it works - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/OYNdZX?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

> The `Set` object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references.

and return the difference from left and right side.

```js
function getSymDifference(a, b) {
    return getDifference(a, b).concat(getDifference(b, a));
}

function getDifference(a, b) {
    var setB = new Set(b);
    return a.filter(v => !setB.has(v));
}

console.log(getSymDifference(["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "pink wool", "dead shrub"], ["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"])); // ["pink wool"]
console.log(getSymDifference([1, "calf", 3, "piglet"], [7, "filly"])); // [1, "calf", 3, "piglet", 7, "filly"]
console.log(getSymDifference([], ["snuffleupagus", "cookie monster", "elmo"]));
console.log(getSymDifference([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

A classic approach by splicing the array to prevent using already visited or searched items to use again.

```js
function getSymDifference(a, b) {
    var aa = a.slice(),
        bb = b.slice(),
        result = [],
        i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < aa.length; i++) {
        j = bb.indexOf(aa[i]);
        if (j === -1) {
            result.push(aa[i]);
        } else {
            bb.splice(j, 1);
        }
    }
    return result.concat(bb);
}

console.log(getSymDifference(["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "pink wool", "dead shrub"], ["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"])); // ["pink wool"]
console.log(getSymDifference([1, "calf", 3, "piglet"], [7, "filly"])); // [1, "calf", 3, "piglet", 7, "filly"]
console.log(getSymDifference([], ["snuffleupagus", "cookie monster", "elmo"]));
console.log(getSymDifference([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Could you sort of explain what this is doing? Also could the challenge be done using my line of coding logic? Am I close?

Comment: What does this 'set' do?

Comment: Although this seems to work quite nicely, I'm almost more inclined to follow some ES7 solutions I have found, as they are easier to understand. I actually don't understand the answers you have given very well after review.

Comment: `let difference = arr1
                 .filter(x => !arr2.includes(x))
                 .concat(arr2.filter(x => !arr1.includes(x)));`

Comment: That is the ES7 symmetric difference function I have found on this website.

Comment: See the second solution you posted follows more of the material I've learned so far and makes a lot more sense logically to me as it is easier to follow based on what I know. I also like the way it works.

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant solution I could find is stated using ES7 apparently. I'll post it below, but if someone could help me figure out how to make my initial code work, that would be appreciated.

```
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {

let difference = arr1
                 .filter(x => !arr2.includes(x))
                 .concat(arr2.filter(x => !arr1.includes(x)));


  return difference;
}
```

Basically this filters the first array based on what the second doesn't have and concatenates on the filtered second array based on what doesn't occur in the first. So it gets both sides, not just one, hence 'symmetric'.

Answer (score 0):

reverse the second array and probably that should ease your task

Array.Reverse method:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp

Comment: Could you further elaborate as to how reversing the second array would help at all?

Comment: after reversing the second array you can sequentially go over both arrays in a for loop and check for equality for each item.

Comment: So I can somehow run two for loops over both arrays that simultaneously compare each item index by index? is that what you are getting at?

Comment: why two for loops? one for loop can check both arrays using the index variable.

Comment: I guess I just said two for loops because I don't understand how one for loop could loop across the length of two separate arrays simultaneously, comparing values index for index/comparing values in some other type of way.

Comment: Although is this problem not solvable using a correction of what I have so far?

Comment: for (let index = 0; index < array1.length; index++)
 {

    var itemFromArr1 = array1[index];
    var itemFromArr2 = array2[index];

    if (itemFromArr1 !== itemFromArr2) {
        .. do your thing here ..

    }
}

Comment: That makes sense, although I'm worried that I would somehow have to sort the arrays first as it seems this takes it index by index as far as I can tell (sometimes in these problems the array elements are just randomly placed and also include strings).